# Create Custom Control with Storyboard XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I created a **custom Control** in a Windows 10 Universal App project, which is containing a Storyboard. The Code of the storyboard is looking like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="StatisticUpdateAnnimation">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RingSlice.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ringSlice">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="45"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="{Binding Angle}">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

As you can see the `x:Key = "StatisticUpdateAnnimation`, the storyboard should be triggered only **manually** in C# code so I do not know how to Play this Storyboard after I created the Custom User Control in the Mainpage file like this:`

```
local:ProgressRing  x:Name="Progress" Margin="7"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="ProgressRing_Tapped"/>
```

The style is like this

```
 <Style TargetType="local:RingPresenter" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:RingPresenter">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Representor, Path=EndAngle}" FontFamily="Vladimir Script" FontSize="48"></TextBlock>
                    <helper:RingSlice InnerRadius="100" Radius="150"  StartAngle="0" EndAngle="{TemplateBinding Angle}"  Fill="DarkCyan" x:Name="ringSlice">
                    </helper:RingSlice>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I access my storyboard?

Comment: You created a Custom control, not a Usercontrol? Can you please post the code of the Generic.xaml of your costom control?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT updated the post - the helper Namespace is defined like this `xmlns:helpe="using:ProgressRing.HelperClasses"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know what is your `ProgressRing.HelperClasser`, here I wrote a sample to show one method using `Storyboard` inside of the `CustomControl`. As we know, `CustomControl` is template control inside of the `ResourceDictionary`, we can for example use `Storyboard` inside of the `ControlTemplate` like this:

Generic.xaml

```
<Style TargetType="local:ProgressRing">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ProgressRing">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="std">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="brush" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
                                            Duration="0:0:2" From="LightBlue" To="Red" AutoReverse="True" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Ellipse Width="100" Height="100">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="brush" />
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Text="111" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in the cs file of this Custom control:

```
public ProgressRing()
{
    this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ProgressRing);
    this.Loaded += ProgressRing_Loaded;
}

private void ProgressRing_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StoryboardPlay();
}

public void StoryboardPlay()
{
    var rootGrid = this.GetTemplateChild("RootGrid") as Grid;
    var std = rootGrid.Resources["std"] as Storyboard;
    std.Begin();
}
```

I played this `Storyboard` here once it is loaded. Here the [Control.GetTemplateChild method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.gettemplatechild) is useful, it helps find the named element in the instantiated `ControlTemplate` visual tree. Then you can get the resource inside this element.

Now if you use this custom control like this:

```
<local:ProgressRing  x:Name="Progress" Margin="7"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="ProgressRing_Tapped" />
<Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Click to play storyboard" Click="Button_Click" />
```

Now you can get the storyboard to play like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Progress.StoryboardPlay();
}
```